# Limiting value of this expression

Tags: limits, taylor-expansion, limits-without-lhopital

How can I find the limiting value of this expression:

$$\sum_{j=1}^N \mu_j^2 \sum_{n_j = 1}^\infty \frac{n_j^2 \overline{n}_j^{n_j}}{(1 + \overline{n}_j)^{1 + n_j}},$$

where

$$\mu_j = \left(j - \frac{N + 1}{2}\right)$$

and $\overline{n}_j$ is some average number. I would like to evaluate the above in terms of some specificed $\overline{n}_j \in Z^+$. Note $\overline{n}_j \neq \overline{n_j}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\begin{eqnarray*}
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} n^2x^{n} =\frac{x(1+x)}{(1-x)^{3} } 
\end{eqnarray*}
Let $\lambda= \bar{n_j}$ Each inner sum can written as 
\begin{eqnarray*}
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}  \frac{n^2\lambda^{n}}{(1+\lambda)^{1+n} } =\frac{1}{1+\lambda} \frac{\frac{\lambda}{1+\lambda}\left(1+\frac{\lambda}{1+\lambda}\right)}{(1-\frac{\lambda}{1+\lambda})^3}=\lambda(1+2\lambda)
\end{eqnarray*}
So the original sum can be written as
\begin{eqnarray*}
\sum_{j=1}^{N}\mu_j^{2} \bar{n}_j (1+2 \bar{n}_j) 
\end{eqnarray*}
Without further knowledge of the $ \bar{n}_j$ 's it is not possible to proceed from here.

Comment: Thank you, but I have a few questions. For the identity you provided on the first line, shouldn't $x$ be identified as $\lambda/(1 + \lambda)$? Also on the second line how did you manage to get the second equality?

Comment: @Sid You are right & that was what  I had written in my notebook. Hopefully the second equality of the second line is now sound.

Comment: The power of 3 should be replaced by power 1. But thank you for the help! I would not have made use of the identity.

Comment: @Sid I have edited.